# MySQL - Order by category_id try to avoid having duplicates close to each other

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

Please bear with my English.

I have a table like this,

```
 id |  category_id  |  product_id
 -----------------------------------
  1 |  1            |  1
  2 |  1            |  2
  3 |  2            |  1
  4 |  2            |  3
  5 |  1            |  4
  6 |  3            |  5
```

I want the output to be,

```
id  |  category_id  |  product_id
----------------------------------
1   |  1            |  1
3   |  2            |  1
6   |  3            |  5
2   |  1            |  2
4   |  2            |  3
5   |  1            |  4
```

So in short what I need is, the `category_id` must be ordered so that it repeats in cycles like `1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3,`...etc.

Comment: that's not going to be possible without some ugly hackery in the main query itself. `order by` by itself can't do this.

Comment: @MarcB : That's fine.. As long as i get the desired result I'm happy :)

Comment: If you need to do something like this with your table I would highly reconsider your table structure.

Comment: About how many rows in total do you have in your table, and how many categories? Although it would be ugly, it might be possible to create an aliased column and order by that using a bit of math

Comment: @KaviSiegel: The categories are 10 in number & there are about 120 records in the table. But they are bound to increase

Comment: I would add another field with index that keeps them in the order that you want.

Comment: It wouldn't take much PHP to do this. Are you sure you want to do this exclusively in MySQL?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a query which gives you that result :

```
SELECT p1.*
FROM `product` p1
JOIN `product` p2
      ON p2.category_id = p1.category_id 
      AND p2.id <= p1.id
GROUP BY p1.id
ORDER BY COUNT(*),category_id;
```

Where `product` is your table.

See [DEMO HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7480f/9)

Comment: really dislike using a group by to concat rows together, mysql is the only one that allows this and it can lead to invalid data since the group by is free to choose any from the group. this can give you a bad product_id in this case

Comment: @JohnRuddell I don't like it as well, but in this particular context - if ID is primary key o unique - it is used correctly

Answer (score 6):

> ...try to avoid having duplicates close to each other

Well, okay. The simplest solution I can come up with is a `GROUP BY 'product_id' ORDER BY 'category_id'`. This would make your table look like this:

```
id  |  category_id  |  product_id
----------------------------------
1   |  1            |  1
3   |  2            |  1
2   |  1            |  2
4   |  2            |  3
5   |  1            |  4
6   |  3            |  5
```

I assume that "category_id must be ordered so that it repeats in cycles" is a translation of "I don't want duplicates near each other".

If you had three categories on product one and on product two, they would group together (1,1,1,2,2,2) but the categories would be numerically ordered (1,2,3,1,2,3). Its not a perfect solution for what you want but it is a simple one that seems you give you what you need.

Any complicated hackery in your query will only slow down the query. While it may not be a problem now, it could be a big problem if you have a lot of records.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
SET @rank=-1;
SET @prior_category=null;
SELECT @cycle_length:=COUNT(distinct category_id) FROM table1;

SELECT id, category_id, product_id 
FROM 
     (SELECT @rank:=CASE WHEN @prior_category!=category_id THEN 0 ELSE @rank+1 END AS rank, @prior_category:=category_id AS prior_category_id, id, category_id, product_id 
      FROM table1 
      ORDER BY category_id) AS extended_table1
ORDER BY rank*@cycle_length + category_id, id;
```

Demo here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5bce3/37

Comment: problem with using variables like this is there is no guarentee of the execution order for your variables. **[However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html)**

Comment: You are right. See my updated solution for a fix! Should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: anytime you do a row by row calculation it has the possibility to not be evaluated correctly :(

Comment: Are you sure? 

*As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same statement. For example, to increment a variable, this is okay:

SET @a = @a + 1;*

Comment: yes, yes I am sure lol.. did you read the rest of that article? `SELECT @rank:=CASE WHEN @prior_category!=category_id THEN 0 ELSE @rank+1 END AS rank, @prior_category:=category_id AS prior_category_id` that is not a set but rather a row by row calculation.. so that could be calculated incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get largest category_id value
$sql = "SELECT category_id FROM table ORDER BY category_id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$maxCatId = $row['category_id'];

//Query for every possible category_id
$resultsArray = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxCatId; $i++) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE category_id = " . $i;
    $resultsArray[] = $conn->query($sql);
}

//As long as $resultsArray is not empty
while ($resultsArray) {
    foreach ($resultsArray as $index => $res) {
        if ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo $row['id'] . ' ' . $row['category_id'] . ' ' . $row['product_id'];
        } else {
            unset($resultsArray[$index]);
        }
    }
}
```

First get the largest value for `category_id`, then loop from 1 to the max `category_id` and store all the result objects in `$resultsArray`. Now use foreach inside a while to output the results.

The `if else` inside foreach echos a record or removes a result object from `$resultsArray` if it has no more records in it. When `$resultsArray` is completely empty, while loop breaks.

Answer (score 0):

You seriously need to think of restructuring your table, you need add a temp field what would categories the category_id and then order by that remp field.
My suggestion is a below.

CREATE TABLE Test1
    (`id` int, t_category int, `category_id` int, `Product_id` int)
;

INSERT INTO Test1
    (`id`,`t_category` , `category_id`, `product_id`)
VALUES
    (1,1,1,1),
        (2,2,1,2),
        (3,1,2,1),
        (4,2,2,3),
    (5,3,1,4),
    (6,1,3,5)
;

SELECT
  category_id,
  product_id
FROM
  Test1
  order  by t_category, category_id